# I don't know how I locked "view offset", but how do I unlock it?

Tags: modeling, 3d-view, camera

When I attempted to navigate within the 3D viewport by using the CTRL-*numpad* options, it didn't seem to work, and I noticed a message in the communication part of the main header that gave the usual warning sign (an exclamation point within a red edged yellow triangle), followed by the text "View offset is locked". The warning appeared and closed so quickly I was not able to obtain a screenshot.

I don't know what I did to cause this, and cannot find any information in the manual or other Blender documentation about this warning message. How do I unlock the "viewport offset"?

Comment: GAndalf3, I looked at that question when I was trying to find out what "View offset locked" meant, and did not find any explanation there for that error message. Since my Q/A covers a specific warning that is not mentioned, when I found out a cause, I posted it. If I get a chance, I'll look to see if it could be edited into an answer on the other question. When I did a "find in this page search on that question's page, the only result was a link to this question; other wise "view offset" had no result there..

Comment: Now it will, thanks to your question an answer :) For this reason, duplicates are actually very useful. The provide a large range of search terms, which can all redirect to a single source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check the *View* tab of in the Sidebar  of the 3D viewport. (Shortcut to open sidebar: <kbd>N</kbd>) This error message can be caused if the user attempts to move the 3D viewport when there is an entry in the "Lock to Object" text box.

Comment: Or “lock to 3D cursor”.

Comment: If the "Lock to Object" input has anything in it (Like "Cube") with an "X" beside it, you can click that X to clear the input; Thats what my problem was.

Comment: How do I find the view/lock to object box among all these options?