# How to remove / revert blender object centre view?

Tags: 3d-view

Using blender v2.76 for a while, I’ve managed to accidentally lock the camera onto an object (The default cube). This causes the zooming to slow down logarithmically once passing the object / space on a certain plain. I’ve tried Numpad + “.” But this only zooms out of the object. Is there any way to remove this centre view?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/644/why-does-the-zoom-sometimes-stop-at-a-point

Comment: Does walk/ fly mode help? (Shift + F)

Comment: You might consult [this question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16267/), or the question of which it is a duplicate to see if this helps.

Comment: Did you try Shift+C or Home button?